Is it possible to disable Gemini in Gmail?
I find it annoying that many messages now show a "Summarize this email" button in the web version of Gmail. Unless I'm mistaken, this button takes up nonnegligible real estate on my screen.

Is there any way to disable or hide this button?

I was surprised such feature exists. So I quickly checked and it's definitely not there by default:

Feature availability

This feature is available as part of our early access testing program, Google Workspace Labs.
To turn off Google Workspace Labs features, exit the Workspace Labs program.
This feature is also available to users on work or school accounts through a Gemini for Google Workspace add-on, and to users on personal accounts through Google One AI Premium. Learn about Gemini features and plans.


Source.
So you just need to exit Workspace Labs or get rid of Gemini for Google Workspace addon. Instructions for the 1st for Gmail:


On your computer, go to Gmail.
At the top, click Settings.
In the Labs program notification, click Opt out.
Click Opt out and reload.


